# R markdown read.csv from saved location given an error in knit

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

When I run this code in the R console, it works fine:

```
train.data<- read.csv("./Desktop/data/train.csv")
```

But when I try to put in into an R markdown document and knit it, I get the following:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> open -> open.connection
Execution halted
```

How to fix this

Comment: Should it be `train.data<- read.csv("~/Desktop/data/train.csv")`? If not check your current working directory with `getwd`

Comment: where is your rmd file? Knitr sets the wd at the location of the rmd file, which may be different from your current wd. You may need to use `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir="/path/to/root")` where the path should lead to the "." directory in "./Desktop...".